# Read fixed length UTF-8 strings efficiently

Tags: c#, windows, filestream

I have a table like datamodel:

`fieldA (10 chracters UTF-8)`

`fieldB(12 characters UTF-8)`

`fieldC (11 characters UTF-8)`

Each field is fixed length and written to a file (local file on disk) without any delimmiters in UTF-8 encoding (written using StreamWriter). The resulting file looks like this:

`fieldAfieldBfieldCfieldAfieldBfieldC [...]`

I also know the amout of records and can use BaseStream.Seek() for random access to the file.

Let's say, I want to read the 29nth record and fill my datamodel, what would be an efficient (fast) approach? I can use StreamReader and read individual char but isn't that problematic because of UTF-8? I wouldn't want to add commas to my data and use the string split method - I am hoping there is a better approach for this in C#.

This isn't for an production use, crazy and micro optimizations are welcome :)

Thanks for you help!

Comment: come on, I wanted to format my post 10 seconds after I posted the question and @Carlos Landeras already did it? Are you a robot Mr. Landeras?

Comment: Nope :). I'm a human being :)

Comment: In UTF-8 a character is encoded in 1 to 4 bytes. So if you have `fieldA` (6 characters) followed by `fieldB` then `fieldB` could start at any offset between 1*6=6 and 4*6=24. There is no way to determine this without decoding `fieldA` first. Possible solution: pad every field to a fixed number of bytes, not characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can seek to the appropriate place in the file, then use `FileStream.Read()` to read the appropriate number of UTF8 characters and then convert it to a C# string by:

```
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Or you can use a StreamReader opened with the correct encoding and then use [`StreamReader.Read(char[] buffer, int index, int count)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824.aspx) to read the correct number of characters (after seeking to the correct place).

**This will only work if you can indeed seek to the correct place, as you say in the OP!**

Read the comments about variable-length UTF8-encoded characters!

Comment: How do you "seek to the appropriate place in the file" if the file contains UTF-8 encoded text?

Comment: Because the OP said "I also know the amount of records and can use BaseStream.Seek()", by which I assumed that the records would not contain any extended UTF8 characters. I'm just basing it on the spec. ;)

Comment: Thanks for all the others that wrote about UTF-8 gotchas. My code only works because I have 1-byte UTF-8 characters at the moment. I have to re-think my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Because utf8 is a variable width encoding (i.e. it uses a variable number of bytes to represent different characters) you have little option but to scan from the beginning.

If you want to calculate and jump to an offset you will need to use a fixed size encoding i.e. UTF-32

Answer (score 0):

> **Each field is fixed length** and written to a file (local file on disk) without any delimmiters in UTF-8 encoding (written using StreamWriter).

You say your fields are fixed length.  That means that fieldA in the file is always 10 bytes (regardless of actual content), fieldB is always 12 bytes, fieldC is always 11 bytes.

Because of the above, the fact that the text is UTF-8 is irrelevant to the problem.

If you open your System.IO.Stream, you can see over the bytes of each field that you don't want to read.  For example, if you wanted to read fieldC, then you could seek ahead 22 bytes (skipping fieldA and fieldB):

```
stream.Seek(22, SeekOrigin.Current);
```

Once you're at the correct location, you can read the fixed number of bytes, then decode those bytes via UTF-8 to your resulting string.